# User click on log in when user already logged in so should throw message.

Tags: users

I am write some code for user login. But i want when user click on log in button every ,that time checks user already logged in or not . if user logged then throw the informative message and if not throws error. How i do this.. Please help me..

Comment: If you reder link through the Drupal way using `l()` function, you dont need to do all these unnecessary things.

Comment: Please add your code to the question for context. It's difficult to understand what you're asking

Comment: Just i want to validate if user is logged in that time if user again click on log in button that time just throw information message to user like "User is already logged".. For that how i handle such situation .. Thats it......

Answer (score 1):

You can check value of field `uid` of global variable `$user`:

> `global $user;`
>
> Contains preferences and other account information for logged-in users. When a user is not logged-in, the `$user->uid` property is set to 0.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/user